# Question about changing macOS Firewall option

Tags: network, firewall, apache, webserver

I have installed Apache Web Server into one of my Mac. And then, I've been publishing this WebServer to inter-net. I'm also using OS built-in Firewall, and allow httpd to external connection.

I happened to encountered this httpd option was changed, httpd have blocked. The timing was seems to synchronized with updating macOS to 14.3.1... but it is not clear.

Finally, I managed to figure out to fix the issue by changing httpd option to allow connection, but I find out a bit funny behavior...

That is, changing macOS Firewall option seems to need system restart to take effect, is that correct behavior?